# How to override javascript function inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, overriding, puppeteer

Page has a script loaded with `<script>` tag containing the following code:

```
window._test = "test",
    function () {
        "use strict";
        function foo() {
            console.log("foo()");
            return "foo"
        }

        console.log("start");
        var a = foo();
    }()
```

I want to override `foo()` function inside that anonymous function with another function, e.g.:

```
function bar() {
    console.log("bar()");
    return "bar"
}
```

One way is to enable debugger and pause execution at `var a = foo();` and set `foo = bar`. But such way requires manual actions.
I want to do this automatically. Basically in Puppeteer or Selenium. After opening page, once script loaded - immediately override that function.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. You could instead look into the possibility of intercepting the request and modifying the code in its response before it even gets executed. Also, there may be other ways to achieve what you want but they would be specific to the real code that this is about and the real change you want to commence, so I cannot answer it universally.

Comment: You can't.  Function scopes are private and you cannot reach into them from the outside and change things.  You would have to somehow intercept the script before it is loaded.

Comment: @CherryDT Another idea I thought about is to intercept request to that script file and replace code itself. Smth like https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setrequestinterception/
But that is very undesirable, as script may have some checksum checks

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, but script may have checksum protection

Comment: @PATAPOsha Then you have to patch the checksum protection away too. You have full power, so you can do whatever you want...

Comment: @PATAPOsha - Ah, I see you've commented while I was researching and writing an answer...where I came to the same conclusion, the only way I can see to do this is to intercept and rewrite the request.

Comment: @PATAPOsha - *"yes, but script may have checksum protection"* But you can intercept the request for the HTML page that loads the script and replace the checksum. ;-)

Comment: It might be simper to disable the script with csp, load the page, enable it again, and add the new script to the DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the normal case, you couldn't do it, because:

1. `foo` is entirely private to the function it's defined in.
2. Moreover, that function is defined and called immediately. So you'd have to be able to modify the source code *before* it was evaluated.

But #2 there brings us to...

> I want to do this automatically. Basically in Puppeteer or Selenium.

Puppeteer lets you [intercept requests](https://pptr.dev/next/guides/request-interception), so you could intercept the request for the file that this code appears in and do a search and replace on that code *before* it's executed.

I've never done it, but it looks fairly straightforward. Roughly:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on("request", (interceptedRequest) => {
        if (interceptedRequest.isInterceptResolutionHandled()) {
            return;
        }
        if (interceptedRequest.url().includes("the-relevant-filename")) {
            // ...read the original file, do your search-and-replace,
            // then...
            interceptedRequest.respond(/*...your updated file text...*/);
        } else {
            interceptedRequest.continue();
        }
    });
    await page.goto("https://example.com");
    await browser.close();
})();
```

That's completely untested, but you get the idea.

---

In a comment you've said:

> yes, but script may have checksum protection

True! But you can intercept the request for the file that loads the script and replace (or remove) the checksum. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also thought about this way. But that is very undesirable, as script may have some checksum protection, and it may be complicated to find it.
Maybe it is possible to go through my "debugger" scenario? But automatically. Like, somehow enable debugger in Puppeteer, set breakpoint automatically in advance...

Comment: @PATAPOsha - I don't see that the checksum would be a problem, it's easy enough to intercept all HTML requests and strip the checksum from their `script` tags (or similar, depending on how that file is loaded). No idea about the debugger thing.