# How to override anonymous function in JavaScript with Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, overriding, overloading, anonymous-function, tampermonkey

I have a function I want to override in an anonymous function with Tampermonkey.

```
(()=>{
     /* other stuff */
     function Zm(e) {
            let {visible: t, onCancel: n} = e;
            const {windowWidth: a} = la((e=>e))
              , {isMobile: i} = a
              , o = Jm({
                isMobile: i
            });
            return (0,
            r.jsx)(Ga.Z, {
                width: 512,
                open: t,
                footer: null,
                className: o.modal,
                onCancel: n,
                children: (0,
                r.jsx)(r.Fragment, {
                    children: (0,
                    r.jsxs)("div", {
                        className: o.modalTop,
                        children: [(0,
                        r.jsx)("div", {
                            className: o.modalTopIcon,
                            children: (0,
                            r.jsx)(Za.Z, {
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: 65,
                                    marginRight: 5,
                                    color: "#FFAA00"
                                }
                            })
                        }), (0,
                        r.jsx)("div", {
                            className: o.modalDesc,
                            children: (0,
                            r.jsx)("span", {
                                className: o.greenText,
                                children: "Change me."
                            })
                        }), (0,
                        r.jsx)(Qa.Z, {
                            size: "large",
                            className: o.button,
                            type: "primary",
                            onClick: n,
                            children: "Got it"
                        })]
                    })
                })
            })
        }

     /* lots of other code */

    const ev = function() {        
    /* 1,000 other lines in function */
    /* Zm function called here */
    ), (0,
                r.jsx)(Zm, {
                    visible: _,
                    onCancel: ()=>{
                        ge(S(a.disabledModal))
                    }
                }), N && (0,
                r.jsx)(Dm, {}), false]
            })
        };
})();
```

How can I intercept to change the code?

I tried adding break points so I could manually intervene, and just rewrite the `Zm` function before execution. However, that does not work. The website just ends up running the unedited script in Brave still. There might be other code that can be intercepted, but this is close to 121,000 lines of Javascript total. How can I override this function with my own version?

For now, I'm just trying to change the line in the `Zm` function, which I've labeled `Change Me`.

I see I can use puppeteer to do this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74150438/how-to-override-javascript-function-inside-anonymous-function#:%7E:text=One%20way%20is%20to%20enable,()%3B%20and%20set%20foo%20%3D%20bar%20.), but I'd prefer to not have to add additional plugins to my browser.

Comment: It's not possible directly, there could be tricks though, which highly depend on the code that you are trying to intercept, so please include it your question.

Comment: It's a function in an anonymous function. I've worked out I need to intercept the script and replace the function with my own.

Comment: What I meant is, if you show the _exact_ function and how it should be replaced (ideally with surrounding code too), we could come up with possible tricks to achieve the result with TamperMonkey. But intercepting the script of course works too, just not with TamperMonkey.

Comment: Example: say, the code contains `const result = Math.abs(x) * 2` and you want to replace that with `const result = Math.abs(x) * 3` then you could temporarily override the `Math.abs` function with a version that checks based on `new Error().stack` whether it's in this part of the code or not and if yes then it would return the result multiplied by 1.5. Hacks like these are possible (if all else fails) but we need to know the exact code, the approach can be wildly different every time. (Of course it's a stinky hack but if the requirement is to use TamperMonkey only, it's all we've got.)

Comment: There's about 10k lines of code in the anonymous function. How much of the code do you need to see?

Comment: Especially what it is that you want to change about it. Or if it's the whole thing, let's see what code calls that function then. Maybe start by describing what it would normally do and what it should do instead.

Comment: Does this script gets loaded by `<script src>` that was in HTML, or how?

Comment: @Dimava Read up on [Tampermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346239/duckduckgo-api-how-to-get-more-results/53161629#53161629) - it might bring significant [joy](https://github.com/cssyphus/TamperMonkeyUserscripts/tree/main/ImproveW3SchoolsCSSColors) into your life : )

Comment: @CherryDT I tried dropping a break point, and just manually modifying the function. However, Brave just ends up running the unedited script anyways. Should I add the website as well?

Comment: Yes of course if you can tell me the whole story of what you want to achieve with this, I could think of a better solution

Answer (score -1):

You may use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii extension to override file content with modified one on the fly

Comment: This solution would require everyone that installs the OP's Tampermonkey userscript to also install this Chrome extension. I suspect the OP wishes to solve the problem himself, in his userscript code.